# Error when I try to use ".when()" in ValidationRules

Tags: systemjs, aurelia

I'm trying to add the following validation on a class

```
ValidationRules
.ensure("disputeAmount").required({ fullMessages: true, message: 'Required' })
.when(a => a.canBeDisputed)
.on(BillItem);
```

**The *required* validation works fine**. But when I add the *when* clause I get this error:

```
[app-router] Error: (SystemJS) TypeError:
aurelia_validatejs_1.ValidationRules.ensure(...).required(...).when is not a function
```

Below are the relevant items from `config.js`

```
"aurelia-validatejs": "npm:aurelia-validatejs@0.6.0",
"aurelia-validation": "npm:aurelia-validation@0.10.0",
"npm:aurelia-validatejs@0.6.0": {
  "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0",
  "aurelia-validation": "npm:aurelia-validation@0.10.0",
  "validate.js": "npm:validate.js@0.10.0"
},
"npm:aurelia-validation@0.10.0": {
  "aurelia-binding": "npm:aurelia-binding@1.0.0-rc.1.0.2",
  "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0",
  "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0",
  "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0",
  "aurelia-templating": "npm:aurelia-templating@1.0.0-rc.1.0.0"
},
```

Is this something to with the **Version** of aurelia-validation? If so how do i update it? (The project is not set up by me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of aurelia-validation is 1.1.1 but you are using 0.10.0

The package.json file defines the version that npm will install when you run `npm install`

If you change the version there and remove the node_modules folder and then run `npm install` you will get the latest version. Then update config.js to use 1.1.1